# How to assert that an exception was thrown regardless of message?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am expecting that if **serial** cannot be parsed with `int.TryParse`, then it will throw an ArgumentException:

```
        if(!int.TryParse(serial,out intSerialNumber))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The serial number is not numeric.",nameof(serial));
        }
```

However, when I test this behavior my test fails:

```
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void throws_argumentException_if_serial_number_is_not_numeric()
    {
        var sut=new mDevice(serial:"something not numeric",patientid:123);
    }
```

The exception I am getting is:

[image]

**The expected exception is indeed being triggered, why does the test not pass?**

The code for the class:

```
public class mDevice
{
    public mDevice(string serial,int patientid)
    {
        int intSerialNumber;
        serial=serial.Trim();
        if(!int.TryParse(serial,out intSerialNumber))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The serial number is not numeric.",nameof(serial));
        }
        if(patientid<2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The patient id must be greater than 1.",nameof(patientid));
        }
        Serial=serial;
        PatientId=patientid;
    }//more stuff after this constructor, but not including it here
}
```

Comment: please add mDevice code

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca ive done just that

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the fluent syntax instead? Makes it easier to separate the test setup code from the code that actually verifies the expectations: `Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => new mDevice(serial:"something not numeric",patientid:123));`

Comment: How are you executing the tests? May be a problem with the test client software? Are you using nunit itself or using integration with the testrunner in Visual Studio?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thank you. i thought the way i was doing it was better since it's more readable...the way i am doing it is through resharper

Comment: ReSharper may not support all the attributes of NUnit, I recall earlier that they didn't support the `[TestCase(...)]`  attributes. I would test the fluent syntax way in one of the tests and see if that helps. Also, which version of ReSharper are you using?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i am using the latest , which is 11 or 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104451/discussion-between-l-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Comment: Which version of NUnit are you using?